# How do I write Java Script calculation for 2 radio button selections?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, acrobat

I am creating a calculator with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I have two sets of radio buttons that need to create a value based on BOTH selections.

What type of part are you testing? (PartType)
-Gear  -Camshaft  -Bearing

What type of defect are you looking for? (DefectType)
-Burn  -Stress  -Depth

If Gear and Burn are selected, value is 10.
If Gear and Stress are selected, value is 70.
If Bearing and Burn are selected, value is 35.

I cannot assign a value to each selection because the combinations are unique.  How do I write this in Java Script?

Here is what I have so far (Which I realize is wrong)

if (PartType == Gear && DefectType == Burn) value == 10

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: whr is your code for this?

Comment: Refere this  http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml

Answer (score 0):

We may have two possible approaches to the issue.

Note: in the following, we assume that the value is to be displayed in a text field. The code snippets shown are part of the Calculate event script of that particular field. If the value is to be used in another calculation, define the variable, and then use its name instead of "event.value".

a) IF the value is calculable from the options (in the sense of "part type plus defect type"), we could set the components as return values for the radio button selections. In this case, the value is calculate quickly:

```
event.value = this.getField("PartType").value*1 + this.getField("DefectType").value*1) ;
```

or, if there is a more complex algorithm/formula, use that instead.

b) IF there is no formula/algorithm to calculate the value, we need a lookup table. In our case, we would define a two-dimensional array, where the elements represent the PartType, and are arrays of the according DefectTypes.

The return values of the radio button fields would then correspond to the index numbers in that lookup table.

We would start setting up the lookup table first:

```
var myLUT = new Array() ;
myLUT[0] = [10, 70, aa] ; // values for Gear and Burn, Stress, Depth
myLUT[1] = [bb, cc, dd] ; // values for Camshaft and Burn, Stress, Depth
myLUT[2] = [35, ee, ff] ; // values for Bearing and Burn, Stress, Depth
```

where aa, bb, etc. represent the values for the accoriding components.

We can define this lookup table either in the Calculation script, but it is more efficient to create a document-level script containing this definition.

The Calculate script would look like this:

```
var pt = this.getField("PartType").value ;
var dt = this.getField("DefectType").value ;

event.value = myLUT[pt][dt] ;
```

and that would do it.

There is one more thing when dealing with radio buttons fields. Even if there must be an option selected, it is possible (and legal) to have no selection as default. Both cases do, however, assume that options are selected. Therefore, we must protect the code by requiring that both groups have a checked option:

```
if (this.getField("PartType").value != "Off" && this.getField("DefectType").value != "Off") {
// now run our code
}
```

We may also have to specify what happens if one or both of the radio button groups are not (yet) checked.